# How to set google map polyline clickable in xamarin.android?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android

I am working in Xamarin Android, I want to set clickable poly line on google map, am using this below code:

GoogleMap.IOnPolylineClickListener

Code:

```
var polylineoption = new PolylineOptions();
                    polylineoption.InvokeColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);
                    polylineoption.Geodesic(true);
                    polylineoption.Clickable(true);
                    polylineoption.Add(latLngPoints);
                    RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    map.AddPolyline(polylineoption)); 

 public void OnPolylineClick(Polyline polyline)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Comment: map.PolylineClick += (sender, args) =>
            {
              this should help you.
            };

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. Mr.Dinesh kumar